# could the MySQL show percent sign (%) in table

Tags: mysql, math, formula

i want to show some data in percent.
i have a mathematics formula like:

```
(qty(S) + qty(B))/qty(id)*100%
```

could i show the result for example like `25%`? how do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a presentation thing, but it's handled in the same fashion.  You need to [change the data type of the result to a string based one](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html):

```
CAST((qty(S) + qty(B))/qty(id)*100 AS CHAR(2))+'%'
```

Comment: @JoshD: I didn't mean for you to delete your answer, just correct the syntax.

Comment: My answer was being misinformative (that's a word now), and fixing it would essentially mean copying your answer. I figured I'd clear away the confusion.

Answer (score 9):

Databases are used for storing *data*. Presentation of data should not be in its responsibilities. By that, I mean you should very rarely thing about storing a string value in the database like `'75%'`.

If you want specific formatting, the best place to do it is after extracting the data:

```
select concat(your_column,'%') as percent ...
```

Because [`concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) expects strings, numeric values are automagically cast into string before joining them together.